# Interfaces containing references to data

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I just learned that in C# you can technically store data in an interface.  See the following example.  With this example Interface and Class:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleClass : IInterface
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

And the sample program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newExample = new exampleClass();
        newExample.id = 5;

        IInterface exInterface = newExample;

        Console.WriteLine(exInterface.id);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I will get an output of 5.  Why?  I thought Interfaces didn't store anything other than a structure.  Does this indirect storing and referencing have a technical term?  Isn't this also kind of bad because this functionality is sort-of hidden?  I would never normally think to reference a property on an Interface to retrieve actual data, that's what an object is for.

Please let me know if the formatting is wrong or I need to clear anything up.  Thanks!

Comment: the value is sotred in the class, but you can acess it throug the interface , if you had two class implementing your interface that would be usefull

Comment: Both your variables reference the very same memory. Why would you expect the same memory to contain two different values? The assignment doesn't copy anything, you just set two references to the same object instance.

Comment: Essentially all you have done is cast the `ExampleClass` to it's interface. The value that you retrieve still comes from the `object` `newExample`. The interface provides a contract that must be provided by the class, therefore we know that if we have an `IInterface` it must provide a property `id` which returns an `int`. There no hidden functionality, you're simply calling the classes interface which is implemented by the `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface isn't storing any data. Think of an interface as (loosely) describing a contract that says "any class which implements me must provide the following properties/methods".

This code

```
    var newExample = new ExampleClass();
    newExample.id = 5;
```

is doing this:

> Create a new instance of `ExampleClass` and assign the value of 5 to
>   the `id` property.

However, this code

```
    IInterface exInterface = newExample;
```

is saying this:

> Cast (change) the instance of `newExample` to an instance of the interface `IInterface`.

What that means is that any time you access the `exInterface` variable, you only have access to those properties/methods defined in that interface (even though your class may have other properties/methods defined).

You can never create an instance of an interface. It's always in the context of creating an instance of a class which implements that interface. If you then cast that instance to the interface, you're using essentially a "least-common-denominator" type approach and restricting access to just what's defined by that interface.

Comment: Ah the "least-common-denominator" type approach idea clicked with me.  Thank you very much for your help!